# Capture Azure EventHub data to Azure Data Lake on a different subscription

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-eventhub

My team publishes data on a Azure EventHub in our own Azure subscription. We are trying to disseminate this data to several other teams within our organization that will need to query this data in their own subscription. I know you can capture data directly to storage by turning on capture for the EventHub and specifying your storage resource, but from what I can tell this won't work across different subscriptions, only stores to a single db, and even if those issues could be overcome would require a lot of overhead by my team adding/maintaining all the other teams db captures. Is there a way to have other teams capture our EventHub data straight to their own storage on their own subscription without our team having to create custom resources/connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to capture the data into a different subscription other than the subscription that Event Hubs namespace is under. Capture over cross-subscription support is a feature that we are still working on to enable in 2022.